# ActiveX control need to be signed

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, dll, activex

i have developed an activeX dll using visual studio 2005.when i run in ie browser it displays "activeX is unsafe to run" warning. to overcome this i have to sign the activeX dll.
can you tell what is the procedure to sign a activeX dll?

i have tried signing using Self signed certificate using openssl and signtool.exe tool, and made the dll signed during the compilation and packaged with the signed dll. After Signing also i'm getting the same warning. Please can anyone give a correct method to sign an dll and use it properly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must purchase a Code Signing Certificate from one of the certificate providers such as Thawte, Verisign, or GeoTrust. They will provide you certificate and private key for signing it.

Otherwise you can self sign your activex control using the tools provided by VS. For that first you need to create the certificate using makecert

see [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfsktky3(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfsktky3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

after creating the certificate you need to sign the activex control using signtool

see [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s9b9yaz(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s9b9yaz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/asiatech/archive/2011/12/05/how-to-develop-and-deploy-activex-control-in-c.aspx) article on how to use makecert and signtool

Comment: still shows the same warning "activeX is unsafe to run". but if i verify the dll it shows "verification successful".

Comment: Message box shows this warning. I have to click yes to proceed

Comment: Follow http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751977(v=vs.85).aspx and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14533/A-Complete-ActiveX-Web-Control-Tutorial